# Sim Based application

Tags: java, mobile-phones, sim-card, sim-toolkit

I have to design a simple application which has to reside in the SIM card of a GSM mobile.
But I dont have any idea how to get started. Till now I have only designed apps using J2ME. Do I need Java Card for SIM based app? 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [SIM Application Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_Toolkit). Check this simlar question too : [Getting started with STK programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536682/getting-started-with-stk-programming)

Comment: sorry - but wikipedia isn't helpful at all in this case :(