# AT + STSF = 1 command returning error while activating sim toolkit functionality

Tags: gsm, at-command, sim-card, sim-toolkit

Recently I'm trying to work with SIM Application Toolkit. I want to get the menu list of the services given by the SIM. For doing that as far I know I have to activate the SIM toolkit functionality using **AT+STSF=1** AT command which several GSM developer guides say.

But While giving that command to set the functionality I'm getting an ERROR result. Meanwhile I'm using a modem which is STK supported.

Whats the actual problem here??

or is there any other way to select the menu of those services provided by the SIM.

I've googled a lot about it, but unfortunately not getting the real answer.

Please help me in this regards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you entered ATI to check that you are on the right port (you should see modem details)? Have you unlocked the SIM? Can you send other AT commands? What error code are you seeing (view the error code by first entering AT+CMEE=1 and then re-trying AT+STSF=1)?  What happens if you try AT+STSF=? or AT+STSF? ?

Comment: Also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536682/getting-started-with-stk-programming

Comment: The modem is on the right port i'm sure. The other basic AT command work fine such as sending sms. AT+CMEE=1 returns OK, AT+STSF=? & AT+STSF? returns nothing, but the AT+STSF=1 returns ERROR. Actually is there any other per-requisite to activate the STK functionality of the SIM card??

Comment: Does the 3rd answer in the question linked above help?

Comment: @HabiburRahman did you get to solve this problem? I am also experiencing similar issues.

Comment: What is the modem model you used?